# my code doesn't work for some big numbers

Tags: c++

I have this code that works for most of the inputs but there are some that throw me error. like " -1000000000000000000 1 1000000000000000000 " for example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;
int x,y,m;
int aux=0;
int toPerfect(int a,int b,int per){
    if(a >= per || b >= per){
         aux=0;

    }else if(a<=0 && b<=0){
                 aux = -1;
           }else{
                 while(a < per && b < per){
                      if(a > b){
                           b = b+a;
                       }else{
                             a = a+b;   
                            }
                      aux++;        
                }
               }

     return aux;
}

int main(){
    cin >>x>>y>>m;
    cout << toPerfect(x,y,m) << endl;
    cin.get();

}
```

Comment: check what `sizeof(int)` is on your system. If it's 4, you can't store numbers greater than 2^32 - 1.

Comment: how can i fix that using long long instead of int? i tried that but doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at an [Integer Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). This question is asked so often here there should perhaps be a dedicated forum with this name.

> ...an integer overflow occurs when an arithmetic operation attempts to
>   create a numeric value that is too large to be represented within the
>   available storage space. For instance, adding 1 to the largest value
>   that can be represented constitutes an integer overflow. The most
>   common result in these cases is for the least significant
>   representable bits of the result to be stored (the result is said to
>   wrap).

Answer (score 2):

The range of some datatypes I've mentioned here. Check it out change your code according to requirements.

```
signed char: -127 to 127
unsigned char: 0 to 255
signed short: -32767 to 32767
unsigned short: 0 to 65535
signed int: -32767 to 32767
unsigned int: 0 to 65535
signed long: -2147483647 to 2147483647
unsigned long: 0 to 4294967295
signed long long: -9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775807
unsigned long long: 0 to 18446744073709551615
```